# What is the right pronunciation of 「何にみえますか」

Tags: pronunciation, questions

What is the right pronunciation of 「何にみえますか」? Is pronounced 「なんにみえますか」or 「なににみえますか」? Why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> 「何にみえますか。」
>
> "What does it look like (to you)?"

「何」 is pronounced 「な**に**」 formally and 「な**ん**」 informally.  That is the only difference.

So, the two are equally 'correct' and neither one is 'better' than the other.

Both mean the exact same thing as well -- "what".