# Is 「何に」 read 「なにに」or 「なんに」?

Tags: kanji

As far as I can tell, this same question has been asked before [here](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/73622/what-is-the-right-pronunciation-of-%e4%bd%95%e3%81%ab%e3%81%bf%e3%81%88%e3%81%be%e3%81%99%e3%81%8b).

However, I am asking it nonetheless because I've noticed that the Genki textbook uses both readings and I find the inconsistency weird on their part if the difference is only a matter of formality.

So, can anybody confirm that both readings are the same? Is there no usage difference besides formality?

I also ask because I've found [this article](https://penzemi.com/%E3%80%8C%E4%BD%95%E3%81%AB%E3%80%8D%E3%81%AE%E8%AA%AD%E3%81%BF%E6%96%B9/) that seems to discuss the difference, but I cannot understand it.

Comment: `I've noticed that the Genki textbook uses both readings` -- Could you show some of their example sentences, please?

Comment: Sure. If you don't mind, I'll link to images: [なに](https://i.imgur.com/XNavI9f.png) (from the Workbook, lesson 12), [なん](https://i.imgur.com/YIuO62P.png) (from the textbook, lesson 15).